# If vectors in a set is linearly independent to each other, does it make the set an linearly independent set? Why or why not?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-independence

A set S has vectors **$a_1$,$a_2$,$a_3$,.....,$a_n$**.
**$a_1$** is linearly independent to **$a_2$,$a_3$**,......**,$a_n$.**
**$a_2$** is linearly independent to **$a_1$**, **$a_3$**,......,**$a_n$**.
**$a_3$** is linearly independent to **$a_1$**, **$a_2$,......,$a_n$.**
......
**$a_n$** is linearly independent to **$a_1$,** **$a_2$,$a_3$,......,$a_(n-1)$.**
does this make the set S a linearly independent set?
Why or why not?

Comment: If $S$ is linearly dependent then one of the $a_i$'s is a linear  combination of the others.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be the set you describe in the question. Let $a_1,\dots,a_n$ be scalars such that $$a_1v_1+\dots+a_nv_n=0$$

This implies that the $$a_1=\dots=a_n=0$$ as if that were not the case, then there would exist a vector that could be written as a linear combination of the other vectors in $S$, contradicting the hypothesis that each vector is linearly independent to all the other vectors.

Trivial point but worth mentioning: None of the vectors can be the zero vector as then that vector would not be linearly independent to the other vectors.